# How Do I pass Values into an imagebutton click event in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to pass some values into an imagebutton click event, something like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton id="imagebutton1" runat="server" AlternateText="5 Star Luxury Villas in North Cyprus" ImageUrl="/download/1/luxury_villas.jpg" OnClick="ImageButton_Click('value1', 'value2')"/>
```

then in code behind:

```
    protected void ImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e, string value1, string value2)
    {
       Response.Write(Value2);
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using `OnCommand` instead of `OnClick`

Then you can specify values in the `CommandName` & `CommandArgument` Properties

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="blah" runat="server" OnCommand="blah_command" CommandName="val1" CommandArgument="val2,val3,val4" />
```

And

```
protected void blah_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string val1 = e.CommandName.ToString();

    string [] othervals = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(',');

}
```