# Get object from ListView when clicking button in the row - ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a question about getting object (or at least ID of an object) from a listview in asp.net when i click on the button in the listview. SelectedIndexChanged event doesnt fire. Whats other option?

My listview with 2 image buttons in it (info and shopping cart):

[image: screenshot]

My aspx code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-left"><%# Eval("naziv")%></td>
            <td class="text-left"><%# Eval("cena")%></td>
            <td class="text-left">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/info_512pxGREY.png" Height="50px" Width="50px" /></td>
            <td class="text-left">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="50px"  ImageUrl="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-basic-2/57/basic2-011_shopping_cart-512.png" />
                </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table class="table-fill" id="tbl1" runat="server">
            <thead>
                <tr id="tr1" runat="server">
                <th id="td1" runat="server">Naziv</th>
                <th id="td2" runat="server">Cena</th>
                <th id="td3" runat="server">Info</th>
                <th id="td4" runat="server">Kupi</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr id="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server">  
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: do you search on internet ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920381/how-do-i-pass-values-into-an-imagebutton-click-event-in-c

Comment: But how to pass value from first TD and second TD? how to get content to pass the value?

Comment: you use a different way to make it work, or hidden input fields...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button is intercepting the event, use [OnCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.oncommand(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnCommand="MyCommand" CommandName="AddToCart" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("YourID")%>' />
```

C#

```
protected void MyCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    var myAction = e.CommandName as string;
    var myID = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument);
}
```